# Powershell installing/uninstalling windows services on a remote machine

Tags: powershell, windows-services, installation

I am using powershell 1.0 and I need to install a service on a remote machine and first uninstall it if it exists.

This is my script I have that installs the service, however, I seem unable to uninstall the
service. I have tried installutil however the service path is a network path which installutil, throws errors over.

I'm sure there must be a better and cleaner way of approaching this.

```
$class = "Win32_Service"
$method = "Create"
$mc = [wmiclass]"\\DUMMYServer\ROOT\CIMV2:$class"
$inparams = $mc.PSBase.GetMethodParameters($method)
$inparams.DesktopInteract = $false
$inparams.DisplayName = "DummyService"
$inparams.ErrorControl = 0
$inparams.LoadOrderGroup = $null
$inparams.LoadOrderGroupDependencies = $null
$inparams.Name = "DummyMessageService"
$inparams.PathName = '\\DummyServer\c$\Applications\DummyMessageWindowsService\DummyWindowsService.exe'
$inparams.ServiceDependencies = $null
$inparams.ServiceType = 16
$inparams.StartMode = "Automatic"
$inparams.StartName = $null # will start as localsystem builtin if null
$inparams.StartPassword = $null

$result = $mc.PSBase.InvokeMethod($method,$inparams,$null)
$result | Format-List
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck on PowerShell 1.0, check out [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) which will allow you to run installutil.exe on the remote machine. If you were on PowerShell 2.0 on both the local and remote machines, you could use remoting to run installutil.exe on the remote machine.